# Why are my div images not filling up the entire div box?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I can't for the life of me figure out why in Google Chrome the images in the .productimage divs aren't completely filling up width wise for the .productbox divs near the bottom of this page here:
http://www.daylightfoods.com/products-beta/

It works perfectly in Mozilla Firefox though.

What I want it to do is for those photos in the Products section boxes to fill up the entire width, just like the boxes up in the Specialty section at the top of the page do. Any suggestions or thoughts? This is a custom coded page within Wordpress.

Is there an issue with the spacing somewhere? Or the CSS? I'm including snippets of the code here:

```
<img src="../wp-content/themes/mightymitty_custom/assets/whiteleaf_greybg.png" alt="White Daylight Foods Logo"><span style="margin-left:10px;font-family:AvenirRoman,Arial;font-size:36px;color:#fff;">Products</span>

<div class="productbox"><div class="productimage"><img src="http://www.daylightfoods.com/wp-content/themes/mightymitty_custom/assets/products/products_corn.png" alt=""></div><div class="productcaption"><strong>Fresh Produce</strong><br>Located in the heart of the Silicon Valley, we are in close proximity and have access to the highest quality produce year around from trusted growers on the Central Coast, San Joaquin Valley and specialty growers along the North Coast.</div>
```

```
<div class="productbox"><div class="productimage"><img src="../wp-content/themes/mightymitty_custom/assets/products/products_organic.png" alt=""></div><div class="productcaption"><strong>Organic</strong><br>As certified organic produce distributors, we source the highest quality Certified Organic produce from trusted growers.</div>
```

And here is a copy of the relevant CSS:

```
.productbox {
display:inline-block;
height:360px;
width:310px;
margin:10px;
background-color:#fff;  
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 30px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 30px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
vertical-align:top; }

.producttitle {
font-family:arial;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold; }

.productimage {
width:318px;
height:210px;
padding:0px; }

.productcaption {
height:140px;
font-family:arial;
font-size:12px;
padding-left:15px;
padding-top:12px;
padding-right:15px;
padding-bottom:10px; }

.producttags {
font-family:arial;
font-size:11px;
color:#9aca3c;
padding-left:15px;
padding-bottom:10px; }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't defining any image dimensions in your code.  Therefore the image will default to it's actual size.

Try something like this in your CSS

```
.productbox .productimage img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Another issue you're having is you have productbox with a width of 310px and productimage has a width of 318px.  Here is a working fiddle for you. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronmallen4/xPXH3/)

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't do anything. :( The problem is still there, unfortunately.

Comment: @PanPan Try defining an auto height and adding productbox to the mix (see edited answer)

Comment: @PanPan also your product box is set to a width of 310px and product image is set to 318px.